# How to fit content into a specified area of screen at game startup in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, screen, startup, display

We are using Unity3D to develop an interesting medical application. By making it very briefly, we have a very large touch screen, hanging from a wall. This screen is fixed to the wall and can not be moved. Patients could be adults or children. Tall or short people and so on. Before starting the game, we perform a calibration phase that consists in trying to understand more or less what the touch range is. That is, a taller person can reach the highest points on the screen, while a lower person can not. The calibration phase then identifies more or less which area is reachable. The result of the calibration (simplified) is a rectangle. We would like to fit the content of the game made with Unity3D to be included within this rectangle. That is, there is some function in Unity3D that allows you to specify when you start the game where you "draw" the elements of the game by defining a sort of "sub screen"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes. It is quite easy, just change the *Viewport Rect* of the **Camera**:

[image]

Also check the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) for completeness (the paragraph *Normalized Viewport Rectangles* reports an example in games field, where the camera is split for a two-players match...you basically want the same thing but with a single camera).

In [this doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html), there's also an example in which the viewport is changed programmaticaly (that's your case). Basically:

```
Camera.main.rect = new Rect(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax);
```